# Calling a function as a variable in another function

Tags: c, numerical-integration

I am a bit new to c-programming, I am trying to integrate a function with the trapezoid rule. My function is this:

```
extern double integrate_trapezoid(double function,double min, double max, double subdivisions)
{
    double h = (max-min)/subdivisions;
    s=0;
    for (k=0; k < (subdivisions) ; k++)
    {
        s = s + (h/2) * (function(min + k*h) + function(min + (k+1)*h));
    }
    return s;
}
```

My question is how can I pass a generic function to this function? I want this integrate_trapezoid function to be able to integrate whatever function I need..

Thanks!
Omer

Comment: Pass a function pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You pass `function` as a [*function pointer*](http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html).

E.g.

```
double integrate_trapezoid(double (*function)(double),double min, double max, double subdivisions)
{
    ...
    (*function)(someValue);
    ...
}

...

double someFunction(double value) { ... }

...

integrate_trapezoid(&someFunction, ...);
```

Comment: Worth adding that functions and function pointers can be freely interchanhed, so `function(someValue)` and `integrate_trapezoid(someFunction, ...)` will do.

Comment: To make the code readable - use a typedef - `typedef double (*integrate_func_t)(double);`